# Open form from listbox selection

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to open a form with a SQL condition set up from items selected in a listbox. I keep getting an error Syntax error in query expression. Which I don't understand because if I create a new query and use the strSQL code it opens as designed. But using it to open a form just produces errors.

```
Private Sub cmdViewDash_Click()
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim PCSGroup As String
Dim strDepartments As String
Dim strSQL As String
strDepartments = ""

For Each varItem In Me.listBox1.ItemsSelected
    strDepartments = strDepartments & ",'" & Me.listBox1.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(strDepartments) = 0 Then
MsgBox ("empty list items")
    strDepartments = "Like '*'"
Else
    strDepartments = Right(strDepartments, Len(strDepartments) - 1)
    strDepartments = "IN(" & strDepartments & ")"
End If

strSQL = "SELECT ProposalTracker3.* FROM ProposalTracker3 WHERE (((ProposalTracker3.[PLCS Group]) In ('ILS','Depot')));"

DoCmd.OpenForm "Dashboard", , , strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you ever use *strDepartments*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only valid SQL `WHERE` clauses are to be used for *whereCondition* argument of [DoCmd.OpenForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openform) not a full `SELECT` query.

Consider concatenating the *strDepartments* into a proper `WHERE` condition.

```
If Len(strDepartments) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("empty list items")
    strDepartments = "Like '*'"
Else
    strDepartments = Right(strDepartments, Len(strDepartments) - 1)
    strDepartments = "IN (" & strDepartments & ")"
End If

strWhere = "(((ProposalTracker3.[PLCS Group]) " & strDepartments & "))"

DoCmd.OpenForm "Dashboard", , , strWhere)
```

Alternatively, open the form as is and dynamically adjust its [`RecordSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordsource):

```
strSQL = "SELECT ProposalTracker3.* FROM ProposalTracker3" & _
            & " WHERE (((ProposalTracker3.[PLCS Group]) " & strDepartments & "));"

DoCmd.OpenForm "Dashboard"
Forms!Dashboard.Form.RecordSource = strSQL
Forms!Dashboard.Form.Requery
```

Comment: I went with your second option and it worked fantastically. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help. Do note: the first option filters the form and can be unfiltered at bottom of form or via ribbon Home tab. But second option cannot be unfiltered.